# Should I make datetime.now() timezone aware before converting to EST?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I have to do a bunch of time calculations on EST terms, is the 2nd of the two print statements the appropriate way to ensure that `datetime.now()` will return the appropriate TZ aware EST time from anywhere in the world?  I assume the reason they are both returning the same values now is because my local time *is* EST.  My logic is to make it TZ aware in UTC then convert to EST so I'm never relying on "local" time.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

EST = timezone('America/New_York')

print(datetime.now(EST))
print(datetime.now(timezone('UTC')).astimezone(EST))
```

gives:

```
2017-11-22 16:58:55.236498-05:00
2017-11-22 16:58:55.237080-05:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These will print the same time wherever you are.  I'm not in EST, and they both give *your* local time.  Local time comes from the default arguments:

```
print(datetime.now())
```

Your first line specifies that you want the time in EST.  The second specifies UTC, but converts that to EST.

Does that clear up the functioning for you?

Comment: Yes this clears it up for me.  I'm not sure why I thought pytz wouldn't override the default args